# Easy to use video editing program for XP

Tags: windows-xp, video, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest video editing program to use on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/28357/what-is-the-easiest-video-editing-program-to-use-on-windows)

First this question is almost a duplicate of this question:

> https://superuser.com/questions/28357/what-is-the-easiest-video-editing-program-to-use-on-Windows

Here are my requirements:

- I am running Windows XP so it must be XP compatible.
- Must be Free or have a trial I can use.
- Must be able to run on a computer that has a 2.8GHZ with 2GB RAM
- Must be simple to use and learn
- Must be able to export for use on web

If the other programs mentioned in the post I mentioned (other than Windows movie maker) are of decent quality and fairly easy to use and learn. Easy is defined as I can load the program and start working with it to do basic editing and building.

Basically I need the ability to fade from image to image and use (do not know correct term) image panning? Where you start at the bottom of a image and pan to the top of it. Same with zooming in and out on an image. Also be able to add in some video and sync this all to music.

Comment: 'best' is subjective - as is easiest. it also depends on what you want to do - simple editing/cropping or more complex things, and what file format you're working with

Comment: I am going to be dealing with images and music mainly. Some limited video and editing will be simple. Easy meaning I can get in and start editing and figure it out without having to watch tutorials for most functions.

Comment: @Lynda: For audio editing, try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I agree with Journeyman Geek at this point, "best" isn't going to get you an answer that is any different than the previous post you already linked to. For all we know Movie Maker will work perfectly for you, but we don't know what you actually need the software for. This should be closed unless it can be edited to actually ask a different question than the post you linked to.

Comment: Movie Maker doesn't work on XP and I have Audacity =>

Comment: @Lynda: Windows XP should include Movie Maker by default, check your Start > All apps > Accessories.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Well I feel stupid. Its there, I read that it doesn't work with XP and did not look. Thanks =>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Windows Live Movie Maker](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker).  Apart from being compatible and free, you can recieve tons of help by pressing F1 or by searching and posting questions on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)